# Graduate program applications that require questionnaires and other non-letter material

Tags: soft-question, big-list, career

In the December 2014 AMS Notices, a letter to the editor (http://www.ams.org/notices/201411/rnoti-p1311.pdf) by Deconinck and Medlock addresses the problem of (math) graduate programs requiring letter writers to fill out questionnaires about applicants or do other tasks besides uploading a recommendation letter, unlike the quick process for job applications on Mathjobs where all a letter writer has to do is upload a letter (once). Deconinck and Medlock suggest that letter writers to graduate programs append a postscript to their recommendation letters urging faculty who read the letter to check how their own graduate program handles applications and get the process streamlined if it has any requirements like the despised questionnaires.

Many faculty may not know what their own school makes letter writers do (esp. if they have not served on the graduate admissions committee).  In that spirit, I propose that we collect here on MO a list of schools that make letter writers fill out questionnaires, as a kind of public service to encourage any faculty who see their own school listed here to go to their graduate school administration and insist that the *math* graduate program applicants -- if not all graduate school applicants -- avoid having any kind of survey as part of the application that letter writers have to fill out. If, in the future, a graduate program kills off the required questionnaire, the answer listing that school could be updated to make clear its passage from the dark side to the light side, so to speak.

Of course the admission websites are designed for an entire graduate school, not just a math department, but math faculty could still tell their graduate school that they make no use of questionnaires, percentage rankings, etc. from the online form, so it is a waste of time and therefore they do not want to make letter writers for the math graduate program see any of that stuff.

If you are writing graduate program recommendation letters this year and think this question is worthwhile, please keep a record of which graduate programs make you fill out questionnaires or do anything else besides upload a letter so that you can come back here and make a record of it if nobody else has yet.

Post one school per answer, ideally with the school name first for ease of scanning, and describe what letter writers are asked to do besides upload a letter.

(There are also some praise-worthy graduate programs where the letter writer has to do essentially nothing besides upload a letter, e.g., UIC and Wisconsin have no questionnaire, and Univ. Southern California only posts a questionnaire at the very end and makes it clear that filling it is not a requirement. Perhaps there should be a separate MO community wiki list for those schools.)

Comment: I applaud the intent behind the post;  I decry its current location.  Please submit to academia.stackexchange and add a link here to it.  Of course, if the community decides otherwise... .  Gerhard "For Keeping MathOverflow Primarily Mathematical" Paseman, 2014.12.16

Comment: Why is academia.stackexchange a better location? Having it on MO is much more likely to bring it to a wider reading by the intended target audience. I'd also like this to be a CW question, although I don't know how to make it one.

Comment: How about the absurdity of these websites asking one to fill in contact information when *tautologically* one wouldn't be filling out stuff on the darn website in the first place if they didn't have an accurate email address! Who designs these forms?!?

Comment: @user74230: I agree.  I know some people who fill in those lines with "See attached form." No graduate program is going to send any letter writer a letter in the mail, so the collection of such information seems utterly pointless.  Programs should stop asking for that kind of stuff as well.

Comment: @KConrad Are you referring to questions such as "what is the candidates potential to be a leader" and vague stuff like that, or do you also mean questions such as "rank in class" and check boxes with "top 1%, top 5%, ..."? Both types are annoying, and generally useless except maybe for initial screening at schools that get many hundreds of applications. OTOH, my experience is that almost all math grad programs pose such questions to letter writers, so you may get a more useful (and shorter) list if you ask for those schools that don't!

Comment: @JoeSilverman: I mean both. Schools that screen quickly probably use GRE subject test scores rather than responses to "rank at a% out of b students in c years." I suggest at the end of my question to have a separate MO list of school not asking for such stuff.

Comment: There is one thing to keep in mind here. Different forms go to different agencies (yes, I support the idea that all higher administration, HR, etc. should be dismissed and all decisions should be made on the spot by a few people who really do the work and care about it, but it won't happen tomorrow). So, when you fill out 3 forms with the same content, you make it for 3 independent and, most of the time, unconnected readers for some of which it may be even illegal to share the info with the other two :-)

Comment: @fedja: I don't see the point, for instance, of asking for mailing addresses of letter writers. How is any part of a university administration going to make worthwhile use of such information? It's tempting to list a mailing address as Cloud Cuckoo Land or Prostokvashino.

Comment: And I was amused to be told by some of these on-line sites that the street address I gave them (the actual math dept address) "did not parse", or something. But, yes, as @JoeSilverman suggests, there're many issues about "leadership" and also questions about class rank (which no faculty would have reasonable means to answer)... Questions made up by people presumably uninvolved with actual admissions, and whose notion of it comes from movies or novels. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett: The UMass Amherst form asks for a percentage ranking out of all the students taught. Someone who has taught a number of large lectures could have several thousand students over the years, making 1% of that total not a strong endorsement. I found that when I tried to enter .5 in the percentage box it was *rejected* because "only numerical figures" are allowed!

Comment: @KConrad the academia site is built for questions and answers with issues just like this.  The only reason to specialize it to math and post it here is that much of the audience you want is here (and I pretend that you want to shirk or otherwise avoid other academic disciplines).  That's why I recommend a link, not deletion.  The topic is otherwise not mathematical and I would not like to see many of these kinds of questions on this forum.  Of course, it is not for me to decide, but the community to accept/reject.  Gerhard "Don't Make It A Habit" Paseman, 2014.12.17

Comment: @KConrad The point is that not only does the letter go to the agency that has little to do with the actual admission/hiring, but it also goes to the clerk whose job is not to think, but to scan, copy, and type in without thinking. So, he needs the address to be always in the same place and to be the address to which to send the correspondence, not the one it came from (in 95% of cases they coincide but in 5% they don't and he has no time or skills to distinguish). I do not see the point of the whole system either, but, if we take it for granted, I see the point of each particular within it.

Comment: By the way, even the streamlined process we now have for MathJobs might be under threat -- this year, three universities made me upload letters for job candidates at their website rather than getting it themselves from Math Jobs.  (Rochester, Vermont and North Carolina).  I hope this infection doesn't spread, or that people will take steps in advance to resist it before too late.

Comment: @Lucia: there have always been some schools that do not allow applications to be uploaded on Mathjobs, even if they advertise there. My department faced that threat a few years ago (i.e., being compelled to switch to the school's own employment application system) but we avoided that fate by (i) finding out from other departments what made the school's own employment site hard to use, (ii) showing an administrator what Mathjobs looks like from both the applicant's and employer's side, and (iii) telling administrators about the website AcademicJobsOnline, which is just like [to be contd.]

Comment: MathJobs but is for all other disciplines. My school's own employment system was so clunky by comparison to AcademicJobsOnline that in fact the internal application system was eventually abandoned and now all hiring is done through MathJobs for math and AcademicJobsOnline for faculty positions outside of math.

Comment: @KConrad Same at the place I am. I insisted on using MathJobs when I was the chair of the hiring committee but we still had to tell the candidates to fill "an academic data form" (or something like that) through the university website for a) criminal background check b) diversity/affirmative action office, and c) something else I no longer remember. Fortunately, that particular form was not too strange or illogical and HR agreed to restrict the additional application paperwork to that form alone.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman One issue with moving it to Academia.SE is that people here would need to make an account there to post answers/comments.

Comment: @Kimball, if someone already has a stackexchange account I don't think it's a big burden to pick up another one, particularly that one. I can imagine there might be some reluctance to set up an account for the "worldbuilding" stackexchange site, but I've seen mathematicians answering questions on the academia site.

Comment: Well, it's not a big burden.  However, there were  many times that I wanted to comment on or vote on something on another SE site, but didn't because I didn't want to bother setting up an account.  And it's true that quite some mathematicians do use Academia.SE, but I guess it's an insignificant number compared to MO.

Answer (score 7):

Georgia Tech

It asks letter writers to fill out a questionnaire about the applicant, including asking how the applicant works as part of a team.

Answer (score 6):

Ohio State

It asks letter writers to fill out a questionnaire about the applicant and also asks if the letter writer knows the applicant well enough to write a recommendation. Excuse me?

Answer (score 5):

University of Minnesota

Not bad -- I was Driven to Discover (SM) that I have to create a password just for using the system that one time. But was able to bypass the survey completely.

Comment: Ah, but in a year or two when you have to use UM's system again, will they force you to remember your password (or force you to request a new one be sent to your email address)!

Comment: Minnesota also has a spot where letter writers are asked to fill in their URL. I filled it in with something along the lines of "Are you serious? Use Google."

Comment: I have to apologize for Univ of MN's shenanigans. These are not generated by the math dept at all, but by a central bureaucratic unit... The application set-up is somehow aimed to be one-size-fits-all for nearly all graduate programs. I've complained, etc., many times over the years, but Central Administration's belief is that academic depts needs lots of oversight and control, or we'd admit just anyone, and grant degrees willy-nilly. Again, my apologies...

Comment: @paulgarrett: Point out to them that programs like UIC and Wisconsin don't make letter writers do any of that stuff, so it's not exactly intrinsic in the nature of graduate admissions that such things must be asked.

Comment: @KConrad, indeed, but/and this centralized "management" of grad admissions is some peoples' full time job, and once it's all in place and they're hired for that job, it's hard to eliminate. Further, some of the computer-not-literate academic departments seem to positively _like_ this central "management", so there is by-far insufficient unanimity to eliminate this fake central unit and its constructs (and senseless burdens on people). Sure, if a Vice President were inspired to do this, it'd be one thing, but for mere working faculty to suggest changes... don't get me started. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett: I'll try not to get you started (oops?). At least the math departments could say they make no use of the questionnaires when making admissions decisions and ask that letter writers for the math graduate programs not see that part at all. Or, if that's too unrealistic, maybe they could be like Univ. Southern California and put the questionnaire only at the end with a big disclaimer saying explicitly "This is not necessary."